Unable to load React Microfrontend app in Angular host app
MFE app:
WebpackConfig
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'remoteApp',
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  exposes: {
    './App': 'singleSpaEntry',
  },
  shared: [
    {
      ...pkg.dependencies,
      react: {
        singleton: true,
        requiredVersion: pkg.dependencies.react,
      },
      'react-dom': {
        singleton: true,
        requiredVersion: pkg.dependencies['react-dom'],
      },
    },
  ],
}),

=========================================================================
WebpackConfig for Host contains :
remotes: {
   "remoteApp": 'remoteApp@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js'
}

Declare the module in decl.d.ts as
declare module 'remoteApp/App';

in app.routes.ts:
{
  path: 'remotePath', loadChildren: () => import('remoteApp/App').then(m => m.App)
}

Getting this error in browser console:
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "remoteApp@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The error is pretty clear, what are you not understanding ?

Would really appreciate if you can help me resolve it.
